# How do I fix a 503 error for successfully uploaded files?

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp

I'm uploading custom wordpress theme files from a mac to a remote server. I am using SFTP with Cyberduck, transferring a variety of file types (php, css, less, png, jpg, gif; typical website files) from my local machine to a remote host, and random files return a 503 error once they're uploaded.

I've tried deleting the files returning the error, and then re-uploading using a different client, that doesn't work. I refresh the remote files list in either of my two FTP clients, and the files are there. I refresh the web page in the browser after waiting to see if it's just that the server is busy... nothing. Same error.

It seems random CSS and image files are returning a 503 error on the server, and I have no idea how to fix this. Any ideas?

Comment: Check the server's error log. it'll most likely have more details about why the 503 is being issued. what you get in the client browser is DELIBERATELY vague/useless to prevent any internal details/sensitive stuff from leaking out.

Comment: I'll have to wait then, as I was just given FTP access to someone else's server to upload the files. I emailed the owner, hopefully he'll be able to help me check the logs to figure it out. Thanks. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggest you upload those files separately. Will it be that uploading to fast because your css/images file are too small such that the ftp server is too busy to deal with the requests?

Comment: I tried to delete the files off the server and re-upload them individually, but that didn't work. The newly uploaded files still return a 503 error. I also tried to navigate to an image file's location in the browser after I had deleted it off the server, but it didn't give me a 404 like I expected: it still returned 503.

Comment: I deleted the folder, and then added each folder manually, and uploaded each file individually. It took a while, but it worked. Still don't know how to avoid the 503s for bulk uploads in the future, but at least my issue is resolved for now. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome!To upload a bulk of files at one time, I think you have to reconfigure you ftp server, say resize the maximum concurrent connections or something else.And the documentations on this site http://filezilla-project.org/ may give you some hints.